# Can't find PInvoke DLL

Tags: c#, dll, windows-mobile, pinvoke, windows-mobile-6.1

When I debug the application it works fine.  The copy of the debug version residing in `Program Files/AppName` dir works fine running stand alone on the device.

However, the CAB installed version of my app, with the DLLs present in the application directory, does not work.

How can this be solved?

*RESOLVED* (Can't answer my own question within 8 hrs with < 100 rep)

Turns out the problem was the device had the DLLs already installed in the Windows directory and the DLLs my CAB was installing were x86 and not ARM.  Removing the DLLs I provided with my CAB solved the problem.

Comment: Surely you can provide a better diagnostic than "it doesn't work"?  Document the exception and explain what you did to ensure that Windows can find the DLL.

Comment: The DLLs were present in the application directory as stated in my post.  Clearly Windows can find them there?  Didn't think any further proof of detection was required.